# Simple solution to send a short pulse to Solenoid for milliseconds?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, solenoid

Imagine a Ding Ding doorbell scenario where we want to save our solenoid from burning if a visitor keep the button pressed for a long time.

For a 12v Solenoid If power button is turned on I want to send a short pulse to Solenoid i.e It activate it for milliseconds and then deactivate immediately and then when power is turned off it again sends a similar short pulse

I am basically an Arduino guy and do not know much about basic electronics I can make this circuit using arduino but for this to work my arduino needs to remain working all the time whereas I am looking for a simple solution for it where I don't have to keep anything ON 24/7,

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: (1) Is it DC or AC? (2) Those normal "dong" on the return stroke. Do you want a ding-dong on press and another on release?

Comment: Yes exactly a ding-dong on press and another on release, 

Either AC or DC it doesn't matter for me as long as solution remains simple , However I will prefer a DC solution for a 12v DC push/pull solenoid , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flKKgZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The low-tech solution.*

How it works:

- C1 is charged via R1 while the SW1 is open.
- On pressing SW1 a high current flows from the capacitor to the solenoid which pulls in giving the "DING".
- The capacitor will discharge and, with R1 chosen correctly, there will be enough current to hold the solenoid weakly in the extended position. (Remember that it will be over-driven to accelerate it hard enough to reach the chime with some velocity.) The idea here is that the holding current is reduced to a safe long-term level.
- On releasing the button the solenoid will retract giving a "DONG".

Time for some measurements and maths:

- Measure the solenoid current. You can do this by connecting a multimeter in amps mode across the button.
- Work out the coil resistance from \$ R = \frac  {V}{I} = \frac {12}{I} \$ or measure it.
- You now need to figure out how much resistance you need to hold the solenoid on adequately. I would guess that a car indicator or brake-lamp bulb would be adequate for R1. You can test by wiring it across SW1, pressing SW1, listen for the "DING" and release. The lamp should be dim and the solenoid will be weakly extended if we've got this right.
- Now for C1: Assuming about 1 A for the solenoid the resistance would be about 12 Ω. If we aim for a 100 ms pulse time we can calculate C from the time constant formula \$ \tau = RC \$. Rearranging we get \$ C = \frac {\tau}{R} = \frac {0.1}{12} = 0.01 \ \mathrm F \$ approx. This is 10 mF or 10,000 µF. You need 16 V caps (the next standard voltage).

This isn't quite what you asked for in the comments but retains the normal "DING-DONG" for a short press and gives a "DING" on press and "DONG" on release for the longer press.

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it and providing a details answer

If I use off the shelf pull/push type solenoid which comes with spring in it wouldn't that produce full DING-DONG while button is pressed and on its release? 

Also what about power dissipation? wouldn't this heat up the capacitor as long as button remains pressed (imagine a scenario where doorbell button gets stuck) and eventually it will burn the capacitor?

pls correct me if I am wrong 

Thanks again for helping me out

Comment: (1) The door chimes use a push / spring-return solenoid. This is different to a push / pull which will maintain its last position with power off. Test your bell. If you only get a "DING" when holding the button and "DONG" on release then you've got the former. (2) Once the capacitor is charged up no more current flows into it. Capacitors so have a very low internal series resistance which causes a tiny amount of heating in very rapid charge-discharge cycles. This is not a problem. It will not burn out. Homework: understand capacitors!